# Gitlab CI Failed: NPM command not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci, npm-install

I have been playing around Gitlabl CI but for some reason I can't get my tests to "passed". It always says `npm: command not found`

My Gitlab CI config looks like this:

```
image: node:latest
# This folder is cached between builds
# http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#cache
cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - npm install
  - npm install eslint -g
  - npm install eslint-plugin-react -g
  - npm install babel-eslint -g

test:lint:
  script:
    - eslint src/*
```

I keep getting the error below and I have No Idea why:
[image]

By the way, Im NOT using the gitlab shared runner. Not sure if that contributes to the problem but just to make sure, the machine that has my gitlab runner has all the necessary packages to run nodejs.

Your help is greatly appreciated

Best regards,

Comment: A naive question, but do you have node.js installed on your gitlab runner?

Comment: Can you figure out under which OS account gitlab runner executes tests? After that you could try to login to that account and verify if npm is available.

Comment: @vsenko Yes- as I mentioned the machine that has my gitlab runner has everything to run nodejs. That means I have nodejs installed. Thank you f

Comment: @vsenko it's under root account. On my runner.ssh I specify user as the root and Yes- it has nodejs installed too.

Comment: Maybe npm is not in in the PATH of root user?

Comment: @vsenko it does. Just to make sure I also installed nodejs under gitlab-runner and added it to sudo group

Answer (score 8):

The `image` tag specifies a docker image, hence you must specify the executor of your runner to be `docker`. Did you perhaps set it to be something else, like `shell`, when you created the runner?

Comment: In my case I was using ssh instead of docker.

Answer (score 2):

You can use like below:-

```
stages:
          - build
          - deploy

deploy-prod:
          image: node:12.13.0-alpine
          stage: deploy
          script:
            - npm i -g firebase-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.

Gitlab-runner use user of 'gitlab-runner' default when it starts. So the user have not root access.

`ps aux|grep gitlab-runner`

1. copy the shell of running
2. change user: 
   run `/usr/bin/gitlab-runner run --working-directory /home/gitlab-runner --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --syslog --user root` in bash.
3. gitlab-ci runner test
4. pass!
5. kill old pid
6. `nohup /usr/bin/gitlab-runner run --working-directory /home/gitlab-runner --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --syslog --user root`

ps: `gitlab-runner -u root` also change user.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

```
n=$(which node);n=${n%/bin/node}; chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cli is taking ssh executer by default. You probably need docker. Try adding tag in your yml script.

```
 tags: [ <your docker image name> ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **sshpass** to pass some command to your server, you'll have to update your **.bashrc** file (file path: ~/.bashrc).

In **.bashrc** file you see following code uncommented, comment it and it resolve your issue.

```
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked greatly for me

```
    before_script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y npm
    - npm --version
    - npx --version
    - gem install dpl
    - npm install
```

Source:
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/bin-bash-line-131-npm-command-not-found/70632/3

Answer (score -1):

In my case, there are two gitlab-runner. There is no node enviroment in the specific Runner.Then I stopped the wrong one